# when should I write a .d.ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend

I've read several articles and I was told .d.ts file is for libraries those are not written in typescript. But I have tried to write a .d.ts file related to business logic, for example: I can get user detail from backend api which includes username, age, gender etc. then I write my own .d.ts file in directory **"src/types/types.d.ts"** which has content as following:

```
interface UserDatail {
  username: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
}
```

then I can use this interface in my bussiness logic without importing it.

but this type declaration file is not written for a js library, is that a proper usage of .d.ts file? what is the best practice in the situation I described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "d.ts" file is used to provide typescript type information about an API that's written in JavaScript. The idea is that you're using something like jQuery or underscore, an existing javascript library. You want to consume those from your typescript code.

Rather than rewriting jquery or underscore or whatever in typescript, you can instead write the d.ts file, which contains only the type annotations. Then from your typescript code you get the typescript benefits of static type checking while still using a pure JS library.

I hope this information will be usefull for you.

Thank you.

Comment: thank you. I understand your answer but, is that the only situation we can use a ".d.ts" file?